# htaccess redirect from subdir to root passing referrer as parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm fairly new to mod rewrite and I am having issues trying to achieve the following for our private forum users. The private forum is in a sub directory of the site called `community`

user clicks an email link:

```
https://www.example.com/community/index.php?/topic/this-is-the-topic
```

when browser goes to forum and the user is not logged in. The forum injects `/login/` into the `{QUERY_STRING}` although it does not show in the URL and they are directed to the website login page and this is the only way to tell if the user is logged in or not in relation to the required RewriteRule.

The URL needs to look like this when arriving at the login page:

```
https://www.example.com/login.php?redirect_to=https://www.example.com/community/index.php?/topic/this-is-the-topic
```

what I have tried is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /login/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/login.php?redirect_to=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

which gets me this:

```
https://www.example.com/login.php?redirect_to=/community/index.php
```

everything else after the question mark is missing...

If I add `%{QUERY_STRING}` after the `{REQUEST_URI}` in the RewriteRule you can then see `login` has been injected after `/community` in the `{QUERY_STRING}` and then a `&ref=` that contains a Base64 encoded version of the original referring URL from the email.

**UPDATE:**

The community is a private forum in the community sub directory
and there are 2 .htaccess files one in the root and the other in the community dir its self.

I have inherited this and to me the htaccess files look a bit messy
We need to make sure all http traffic is forced to https

Root .htaccess file

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^tribe.mytechnologybusiness.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://tribe.mytechnologybusiness.com/$1 [L,R=301]
# End Replacement

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# BEGIN MainWP
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^wp-content/plugins/mainwp-child/(.*)$ /wp-content/plugins/THIS_PLUGIN_DOES_NOT_EXIST [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
# END MainWP
```

community .htaccess file

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

############################################
# WordPress to IPBoard Integration
# Start Board to Wordpress Redirect Area
############################################
RewriteEngine on

# Registration
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /register/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://tribe.mytechnologybusiness.com/wp-login.php?action=register [L,R=301]
# Logout
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /logout/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://tribe.mytechnologybusiness.com/wp-login.php?action=logout [L,NE,R=301]
# Login
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /login/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://tribe.mytechnologybusiness.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

############################################
# End Board to Wordpress Redirect Area
############################################
```

and the url I am trying to use to test this with is

```
https://tribe.mytechnologybusiness.com/community/index.php?/topic/162-sydney-tribal-meetup-thursday-14th-september-2017/
```

can anybody help me with this?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as **first rule** in your `/community/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /login/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(community/index\.php\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /wp-login.php?redirect_to=https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]

# rest of your rules go here
```

Comment: thanks for that. it didn't work for me... I have other rules in the file. some from WordPress and others that are to force http to https redirects. the community dir has its own htaccess file as well.
is there a way I can send you more details and copies of the 2 files?

Comment: tried as you suggested but still no go. So I have updated the question with all the information you said. Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: No matter where I put the new rule the one being triggered is the `Login` rule at the bottom of the `/community/.htaccess` any other ideas?

Comment: No other rules but yours and this is the result.
`https://tribe.mytechnologybusiness.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Ftribe.mytechnologybusiness.com%2Fcommunity%2F`
We are using Invision Power Board and I have looked all thgrough it settings and there is nothing I can see that causes any kind of redirect.
There are no plugins that force any kind of redirects in the WP site but Memberium passes the `/wp-login.php?redirect_to={{current.url}}` as a default redirect for page content protection

Comment: added rule and it worked fine... added other rules back with yours as the first and all good... You my friend are an absolute dead set LEGEND.... Thank you so much for all your help....

Comment: Sorry to bother you again... but the rule redirects all traffic now even when someone has already logged in.
We only need the redirect to trigger if `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /login/(.*)$ [NC]`
is that possible?

Comment: There is no need to un-accept the answer to get further help. I always try to help as much as I can. Your source URL: `https://tribe.mytechnologybusiness.com/community/index.php?/topic/162-sydney-tribal-meetup-thursday-14th-september-2017/` doesn't show any query string so `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /login/` won't work. What are ways to detect whether is user is logged in r not?

Comment: sorry about that... still getting used to all the etiquette. the `/login/`does trigger and is a value in the `{QUERY_STRING}` if i add `%{QUERY_STRING}` to the end of the original `/login/` rule i get the following... [screen shot](https://i.imgur.com/imeGf2v.png) I tried to post the link as code but it gave an error...

Comment: if I add `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /login/` between `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} etc...` and `RewriteRule ^ /wp-login.php etc...` i get the following `https://tribe.mytechnologybusiness.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https://tribe.mytechnologybusiness.com/`

Comment: in Chrome, Edge and Firefox i get `https://tribe.mytechnologybusiness.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https://tribe.mytechnologybusiness.com/community/index.php?/login/&ref=aHR0cHM6Ly90cmliZS5teXRlY2hub2xvZ3lidXNpbmVzcy5jb20vY29tbXVuaXR5L2luZGV4LnBocD8vdG9waWMvMTYyLXN5ZG5leS10cmliYWwtbWVldHVwLXRodXJzZGF5LTE0dGgtc2VwdGVtYmVyLTIwMTcv`

Comment: I'm not usre I understand... the `/login/` condition is being met as its doing something and not being ignored. the value of `ref` in the `{QUERY_STRING}` is this `https://tribe.mytechnologybusiness.com/community/index.php?/topic/162-sydney-tribal-meetup-thursday-14th-september-2017/` in Base64 have you any suggestions.

Comment: May be I misunderstood then. You wanted this rule to fire when query string has /login/ and that is what this rule did. Can you clarify what didn't work and what is expected behavior?

Comment: I have re written the original question and added what i think you have asked for. I hope this is what you need if not please let me know.

Comment: I've updated my rules. You need to test it after clearing browser cache. I didn't understand what is `&ref=` parameter since that is not there anywhere in my rule. May be it is coming from your php code.

Comment: This is what I get...
`https://tribe.mytechnologybusiness.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https://tribe.mytechnologybusiness.com/community/index.php?/login/&ref=aHR0cHM6Ly90cmliZS5teXRlY2hub2xvZ3lidXNpbmVzcy5jb20vY29tbXVuaXR5L2luZGV4LnBocD8vdG9waWMvMTYyLXN5ZG5leS10cmliYWwtbWVldHVwLXRodXJzZGF5LTE0dGgtc2VwdGVtYmVyLTIwMTc=`
you can see the `/login/` and the `&ref=` in the URL... the value of the `ref` is the referring URL in Base64
Invision Power Board is changing the `{QUERY_STRING}` value as i mentioned before

Comment: Yes I see `&ref=...` in URL but I don't understand what exactly is problem with this final URL. About `ref` I have already mentioned that `ref=` is not there anywhere in my rule. May be it is coming from your php code.

Comment: Thanks for your input and hard work. Based on your observation I went back to the SSO developers and had them look at the issue. They have written a fix into the PHP code.